# CSS - изменить цвет черно-белой картинки

Tags: html, css

Есть картинка, например
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Она черно-белая, можно ли в ней сменить цвет на красный, зеленый и т.д.?

Comment: filter: sepia() saturate(1000%) hue-rotate(30deg)

Comment: Сделать её цветной или наложить какой-нить фильтр? Просто первое не реализуемо если исходник чб.